# ループの途中で条件に応じて値を変更する方法について

Tags: python, 数値解析

以下のコードでは、tが 0.0 ～ 5.0 の範囲で動作が繰り返されていると思いますが、「tが 0.15 より大きくなったら、Eを 1.2 にする(最初はE=0.38)」という条件を付けくわえることはできるでしょうか?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, v, t):
    M=1.0 
    E=0.38
    D=0.1
    return (M-E*np.sin(x)-D*v)/J

J = 0.00424 # 
t0 = 0.0
t1 = 5.0

N = 500



del_t = (t1-t0)/N # time grid

tpoints = np.arange(t0, t1, del_t)
xpoints = []
vpoints = []

# initial condition
x0 = 0.65345
v0 = 0.0


x, v = x0, v0


for t in tpoints:

        xpoints.append(x)
        vpoints.append(v)

        k1v =f(x, v, t)*del_t
        k1x = v * del_t

        k2v =  f(x+k1x/2, v+k1v/2, t+del_t/2 )*del_t
        k2x =(v+k1v/2)*del_t 

        k3v =f (x+k2x/2, v+k2v/2, t+del_t/2 )*del_t
        k3x =(v+k2v/2 ) *del_t 

        k4v = f(x+k3x, v+k3v, t+del_t )*del_t
        k4x = (v+k3v )*del_t 



        v += (k1v + 2 * k2v + 2* k3v + k4v)/6
        x += (k1x + 2 * k2x + 2* k3x + k4x)/6

    print(x)

plt.plot (tpoints, xpoints, 'o',label='4th order Runge-Kutta')
plt.xlabel("t",  fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel("x(t)",  fontsize=24)

#tt=np.arange(t0, t1, 0.01*del_t)
#plt.plot (tt, np.sin(tt), '-',label='Exact: Sin (t)',color = 'Green')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()

plt.plot (tpoints,vpoints, 'o',label='4th order Runge-Kutta')
plt.xlabel("t", fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel("v(t)", fontsize=24)

#tt=np.arange(t0, t1, 0.01*del_t)
#plt.plot (tt, np.cos(tt), '-',label='Exact: Cos (t)', color = 'red')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def f(x, v, t):`の中の`E=0.38`を変えるだけで良いのなら、以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
E=0.38 if (t <= 0.15) else 1.2
```